# React json Data inside value check validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am using React application I have an issue I want to validate the JSON file is empty or not, I know how to validate `{}` this kind empty, But my JSON structure is

```
{
    name:"",
    email:"",
    dob:"",
    password:""
}
```

I have default structure value how to validation inside the value are empty or not like whole empty check likewise

Comment: How about compare both values using JSON.stringify()?

Comment: Set your default structure to `{
    name:undefined,
    email:undefined,
    dob:undefined,
    password:undefined
} ` then you can check if it's undefined or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
myJSON = {
    name:"",
    email:"",
    dob:"",
    password:""
} 

let jsonValid = true
Object.keys(myJSON).forEach((key)=> {
    if(myJSON[key] == "") {
    valid = false
  }
})

console.log(jsonValid)
```

It iterates over the each key of the JSON object, if the key's value is an empty string, it will change the value of the jsonValid variable to false/